# Set custom attributes of App in Apigee using Javascript/AssignMessage policy

Tags: javascript, api, apigee

In my sample app, there are multiple custom attributes.
When a proxy endpoint is called, I would like to have a javascript policy to set one of the app attribute value on the fly.

I tried adding a javascript policy and the following code.

```
context.SetVariable("app.attribute-name", "value");
```

But this doesn't seem to do the job.
I could not find any documentations either. Do you guys have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **context.setVariable("attribute-key", "attribute-value")**. The "s" in setVariable should be in lowercase.

https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/reference/javascript-object-model#contextobjectreference